there is a bug in the 'strategy.exit( )' ? Why is strategy.exit() only condition once, but it is actually always working?
//@version=5
strategy("RsI strategy", overlay=true)
length =input( 14)

var p = close
var stop =false
vrsi =ta.rsi(close, length)
co =ta.crossover(vrsi,75)
cu=close >p*1.0

var bool sell = na
if (not na(vrsi))
    if(co)
        p := close
        log.info('entry: {0}  :size:  {1}',strategy.position_entry_name,strategy.position_size)
        strategy.order("RsiLE1",strategy.long,qty = 10)

    if(cu and strategy.position_size >0 and not stop)
        log.info('stop: {0}   size: {1}', stop,strategy.position_size)
        stop := true            
        strategy.exit('stop',"RsiLE1", qty = 6, profit = 0.1)

I wanted to understand the behavior of strategy.exit(), so I restricted its conditions to allow it to run only once, but in fact it ran multiple times, on each long order:

But why does this happen?

in fact the strategy.exit is running all the time

var p = close
cu = close >p*1.0

cu will always be false.
Then you will never have the "if" strategy.exit (stop).
